# PostgreSQL update Primary key column with random integer values

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with the Integet column as a Primary key. For testing purpose, I want to restore the table to a test server and randomly change the ID column.

Something like

```
select ('9985'||id)::int from table;
```

But updating is not working as I expected.

```
update test set id=(select ('9985'||id)::int from test);
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
 update test set id = ('9985'||id)::int
```

You don't need the from part